# Allocating large arrays; OutOfMemoryException VS OverflowException

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following:

```
long size = int.MaxValue;
long[] huge = new long[size];     // throws OutOfMemoryException
long[] huge = new long[size + 1]; // throws OverflowException
```

I know there is a 2GB limit on the size of a single object, which explains the first exception, but why do I get a different exception once the number of elements surpasses 32bits?

(I am using a 64-bit computer if that's important).

EDIT: I can also define and use an indexer that accepts a `long` with no problems:

```
internal sealed class MyClass
{
   public object this[long x]
   { 
      get
      {
         Console.WriteLine("{0}", x);
         return null;
      }
   }
}

...

long size = int.MaxValue;
MyClass asdf = new MyClass();
object o = asdf[size * 50]; // outputs 107374182350
```

Comment: Use a generic `List<long>` instead which uses only as much memory as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from what I've gathered, something like the following is happening here:

- Indexers in general could use any type of parameter.
- The built-in array indexers can accept any integral type...
- **But** the underlying implementation of the built-in array indexers requires a value that is `<= Int32.MaxValue` and will throw an overflow exception for a value that exceeds `Int32.MaxValue`.

While the latter point feels like some kind of weird contradiction (accepting types larger than `Int32`, but throwing an exception if you happen to actually use any of those extra bits), it is apparently a side-effect of the fact that some of this is half-implemented for the future implementation of arrays which will be allowed to have more than `Int32.MaxValue` elements.

Answer (score 8):

C# arrays are indexed by `System.Int32`. Since `size + 1` is beyond `Int32.MaxValue`, you get an integer overflow.

Use the overload of `Array.CreateInstance` that takes a long instead, if you really want to use a `long` as index.

Comment: so, we are permitted to use a `long` variable as an index or size specifier, but only if the value is not greater than 32-bits? that seems odd; shouldn't the compiler require an `Int32`? Why use `long`s as indexes at all if 32-bits is the index limit?

Comment: Through array subscripting (indexers: `[index]`) you can only use `int`. If you want to use a `long` you have to use the `GetValue` and `SetValue`methods.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `Array.CreateInstance` doesn't solve the problem. You still cannot create too large an array. A related question is asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945404/why-is-long-being-allowed-as-array-length-in-c/10945507#10945507), as of .NET 4.5, larger arrays are supported on 64-bit systems. All integral types can be used as array initializers at compile time.

Comment: @Cicada I seem to be able to use a `long` indexer.

Comment: @Sahuagin The array size limitation is a CLR shortcoming, not a language shortcoming. Language support sort of exists, it's the runtime that usually gives you grief. This is changing as of .NET 4.5.

Comment: @Cicada Yes, I definitely can define and use a `long` indexer, and I can even pass it a value equal to or greater than `int.MaxValue + 1` and use it.

Comment: @Sahuagin Can you please post the code for that? I cannot achieve that using a console app targeting 64-bit, I can't even create the array - runtime errors. You can use all integral types as indexers and size initializers, it's the actual value inside them that is checked at runtime.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I can't instantiate an array that big, but I can define and use an indexer property using a value that big. I have posted an example.

Comment: @Sahuagin A custom indexer can take anything as a parameter. We are talking about arrays. They are not comparable. Either way, a long can be supplied to an array, but as yet it would be pointless.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Ok sorry for the confusion, but that is what 'indexers' are; I have not seem them called 'custom indexers'; they are simply 'indexers'. It seems like this all boils down to differences between what C# and CLR specifically allow.

Comment: @Sahuagin They are the same, the difference is you coded the indexer in your example and the BCL team coded the index on the array. The question was "can you index arrays using `long`", not can indexers use `long`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth well, you can index arrays using `long`, you'll just get an exception if the actual value exceeds 32bits. So they must cast the `long` down to an `int` somewhere I guess.

Comment: @Sahuagin Yes, as I've stated a few times, you can use any integral type as indexers and size initializers so long as the value is not too large (or negative).