# Wrong logarithm of BigInteger when size of BigInteger exceeds ¼ gigabyte

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger, logarithm, base-class-library

When I have a `BigInteger` whose size exceeds 2 gigabits (that's ¼ gigabyte; I found this threshold by trial and error), the logarithm method gives a wrong answer. This simple code illustrates:

```
  byte[] bb;

  bb = new byte[150000001];
  bb[150000000] = 1;  // sets most significant byte to one
  var i1 = new BigInteger(bb);
  double log1 = BigInteger.Log(i1);
  Console.WriteLine(log1);   // OK, writes 831776616.671934

  bb = new byte[300000001];
  bb[300000000] = 1;  // sets most significant byte to one
  var i2 = new BigInteger(bb);
  double log2 = BigInteger.Log(i2);
  Console.WriteLine(log2);   // Broken, gives negative number, should be twice 831776616.671934
```

Of course we must have a positive log for a number exceeding `1`, a zero log for the number `1`, and a negative log for a number between `0` and `1` (no integers there). My numbers `i1` and `i2` above are greater than `1` since, by convention, when the most significant byte is between `0` and `127`, that means positive `BigInteger`.

Now, if you read the documentation for [`BigInteger.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268263.aspx), they claim it might throw if the logarithm "is out of range of the Double data type". Now, clearly that would require a computer with a memory storage of more than `1E+300` bytes, and the observable universe is much too small to contain such a computer, so I guess that will never happen.

So why doesn't this work?

PS! Size over `2 ^^ 31` bits means that the actual value of the `BigInteger` is over `2 ^^ (2 ^^ 31)`, or approximately `circa 8.8E+646456992`.

---

UPDATE: I sent in [a bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776946/wrong-logarithm-of-biginteger-when-size-of-biginteger-exceeds-gigabyte) to Microsoft Connect. After having read the discussions I have also become aware that because of the design of `BigInteger` and the upper limit of 2 gigabyte for the size of one single object, a `BigInteger` can never be over 2 gigabyte (no matter how much memory you have). This bug happens, therefore, when the `BigInteher` is between ¼ and 2 gigabytes.

Comment: 32 or 64 bit architecture?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003719/log-of-a-very-large-number
Or perhaps related?

Comment: @Pete Good find, but I think thats why he's initializing an extra byte. Unless the byte array needs to be terminated with a character in some way that the 1 is becoming the sign character.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen Could you tell us what the output of log2 actually is, or is it different everytime?

Comment: @glace: It seems to be reliably `-1313491238.4757` when I test it.

Comment: You can't make a number that big in the first place.  If you try `BigInteger.Pow(i1, 2)`, which would be the same number, you get `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: @DWright It's 64-bit hardware. I tried changing the build configuration between `x86` and `x64` "platform" but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @glace (to your second comment) I get the same number as mellamokb mentions, consistently.

Comment: @mellamokb (to your second comment) I don't know if you're referring to a deleted comment, but whether you get out-of-memory or not depends on how much memory (probably memory without "holes" in it) can be allocated. I _can_ calculate the square `Pow(i1, 2)`, and it is equal to `i2` (when I test with `==` operator).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: My second comment was a general comment directed to you :).  Ya I was wondering the same thing - I do have 6GB ram free, so that seems a little odd.  Have you tried the suggestion I posted on Daniel's answer with `Array.CreateInstance`?  That might allow you to get it working on your machine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let me guess: The value is

```
-1.3134912384757032e9
```

(modulo small variations in computing the logarithm)?

The index of the highest set bit is stored and passed in an `int`, and

```
8*300000000 = 2400000000 > 2147483647
```

so the index wraps around to a negative number, namely `-1894967296`, and

```
-1894967296 * log 2 = -1.3134912384757032e9
```

Oops. Somebody should file a bug report.

Comment: Actually I think that's by design.  You have to use [`Array.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z8w3at5.aspx) to [allocate an array taking up more space than `int.MaxValue`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10946548/116614). However, if you do use `Array.CreateInstance` with the long-index overload, you get an `OutOfMemoryException` due to the [per-object max size limit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5791912/116614).  So the array being created by the OP is in fact not even `300,000,001` elements in the first place.

Comment: But it's just the number of **bits** that exceeds that limit. The array takes only ~300MB, that shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: Hmm.  I bet there's something intermediate going on internally that is generating an object that's too large.  I've got 6GB free RAM on my machine, so it seems like it should have worked.

Comment: This answer explains what's going on, I guess. I'm considering filing that bug report. The value is the one you quote (except it's formatted to a string without the `e9` notation in my example, but you got the right number).

Comment: @mellamokb The array _is_ 300 million and 1 elements (each element is a byte). So it's over 2 gigabits, but not over 2 gigabytes (there's this factor 8, which is why I wrote ¼ gigabyte). But if the array used internally (by `BigInteger`) is limited to 2 gigabytes, then that sets an effective limit on how big a `BigInteger` can become, and I'm over one eighth of that level (if it exists).